# Is there a term for clause in a sentence that can be removed without invalidating the remainder of the sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Take, for example, the sentence "The dog, which is in the corner of the room, is barking.". Is there a specific term for the part of the sentence "which is in the corner of the room", which can be removed to leave the valid sentence of "The dog is barking."?

Comment: It's a 1. **parenthetical**: "a construction that can be used to extend the meaning of a word or phrase but is not one of the main constituents of a sentence" and more broadly, 2. an **adjunct**: "word or phrase that adds information to a sentence and that can be removed from the sentence without making the sentence ungrammatical"

Comment: In this case _"which is in the corner of the room"_ is a _non-defining (or non-restrictive) relative clause_. But what do you mean by '_invalidating the remainder of the sentence'_? Do you mean _making the remainder sentence ungrammatical_? I suspect you can remove most dependent (subordinate clauses) and leave a grammatical fragment.

Comment: @Shoe "...and leave a grammatically complete sentence," rather.

Comment: @Kris. Yes, your wording is better. I meant that the fragment of the sentence that is left after removal of the dependent clause would be grammatical. But as the term "_fragment sentence_" generally refers to an incomplete sentence, it would not be surprising if my comment is misunderstood.

Comment: Note that "invalidating" is a loose term here.  You could very easily change the meaning if there are multiple dogs in the room.

Comment: One term is 'non-restrictive'. Such items can be dropped without altering the basic proposition of the matrix clause. It covers relative clauses and supplements (including non-restrictive appositives) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Parenthesis. It derives its name from the punctuation marks called parentheses, curved brackets — one but not only device employed to mark off any dispensable amplifier be it a phrase, clause , word or sentence. They can be marked off without hampering the meaning of the main sentence or relevant sentence by such punctuation marks as round or square brackets, comas, or dashes.

Any modifier appearing after the noun or pronoun, an appositive, a noun in vocative use, asides in dramas or absolute phases or nominative absolute can safely be called a Parenthesis.

- The dog, which is in the corner of the room, is barking.

The portion marked of by comas can be so done by brackets or dashes as well. It is an example of parenthesis. The spelling is  different from that punctuation mark, parentheses it lends its name to.

Comment: I'd be inclined to call it a 'non-restrictive element'. Such elements can be dropped without altering the basic proposition.

Comment: Yes, you're right but it's mostly used for adjective clauses non-defining in nature.